# Python Beautiful Soup only scraping the lower part of the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull product info from a rather large apparel website page, but soup only appears to scrape a lower half of the html document, at an arbitrary cutoff, so the data that I'm interested in is not actually in my soup. I've tried it on another website and it worked fine, so I assume it's website specific.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.pullandbear.com/rs/man/sale-c1030036006.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: looks like what you want is probably being rendered by javascript which afaik will not show up with BS4

Comment: Use any browser simulator to grab the dynamic content.

Comment: @novice-coder Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: @aws_apprentice That still doesn't explain why my soup doesn't have the entire first half of the page. For example, it doesn't contain the opening html and body tags, but it includes the closing tags in the end of the document.

Comment: the content is loaded on a js event so bs4 cant find the elements. Try to use selenium to get the entire webpage, save the html and do your thing with bs4...

Comment: @hansTheFranz Tried it, not working.

Comment: The problem is not with `BeautifulSoup`, but with `requests` itself. The response contains only the bottom part of the page source (as you said).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments the HTML you are trying to get is added with JavaScript running on the browser.

I recommend you this package [Requests-HTML](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) created by the author of very popular [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.pullandbear.com/rs/man/sale-c1030036006.html')
r.html.render()

print(r.html.html)
```