# Data missing on requests.get() Python 2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to webscrape the IAA Consensus price on https://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp?txtSymbol=PTT&ssoPageId=9&selectPage=10

In Google chrome inspect elements, I can use `<h3>` through beautifulsoup to get the data. But from the print page.content I get

```
...
<h3 class="colorGreen"></h3>
...
```

Where it should be `<h3 class="colorGreen">62.00</h3>`

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findPrice(Quote):
    link = "http://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp?txtSymbol="+Quote+"&ssoPageId=9&selectPage=10"
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

    print page.content
    target = soup.findAll('h3')
    return target.string

findPrice('PTT')
```

Comment: Its likely that content is loaded using Javascript/AJAX. That would explain why your browser sees it, but your requests response does not.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @user3625025 you can use chromes devopler tools right click > inspect > network (check Preserve log to keep logs when you reload page) > and check all requests one by one

Comment: Ultimately, you need to find the endpoint that is used to provide this data, then request that. The response would likely be JSON or XML.

Comment: Browsers show you the *object model of a page*, not the source that is served at a URL. Javascript and the HTML standard both can cause a browser to add, remove and change objects in the object model.

Comment: In other words: use *view source*, not the *inspection* tab in the browser developer tools.

Comment: @user3625025 either use [@Nicarus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921693/nicarus) approach or take a look at [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682573/4796844).

Comment: In this case the source view of the page (`view-source:https://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp?txtSymbol=PTT&ssoPageId=9&selectPage=10`) shows that there is no data in that specific `h3` element, so it is put there by Javascript code running in the browser after loading the page. `requests` is not a browser, it doesn't execute Javascript code.

Comment: @FatihKılıç Sorry I can't see the check all requests one by one. And will this help Python get the data? By the way I use MacOS X El capitan, Chrome latest version (67.0.3396.62).

Comment: as the @Nicarus says you would have to find the endpoint where is the site gets these datas, if you can find the endpoint you can use in your code directly without using beautifiulsoup

Comment: Thank you everyone. I get the point now. @Jatimir I tried your example and approach but there's some error about the implementation. like this
  File "/Users/xxxx/Documents/Python project/StockDaytrade/htmlrequest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 20
    def __init__(self, *, element, html=None, url):

Comment: @user3625025 Only Python 3.6+ is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the server is checking for a `LstQtLst` cookie and generates the HTML with the "Consensus Target Price" filled in.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_price(quote):
    link = ('http://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp'
            '?txtSymbol={}'
            '&ssoPageId=9'
            '&selectPage=10'.format(quote))

    html = requests.get(link, cookies={'LstQtLst': quote}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find('h3').string
    return price
```

```
>>> find_price('PTT')
62.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no basic about webpage, cookies. I think it's time to dive deeper. Can you recommend some reading sources?

Comment: @user3625025 sorry, I can't think of anything specific right now :/ good luck with your project! :)